# How long should installing Ubuntu take?

Tags: system-installation, 12.10

How long does it take Ubuntu 12.10 to install? It has been over an hour and a half. It says *installing* but nothing is happening.

Comment: If you are connected to internet it downloads language files & updated repos which takes long time. Offline installation takes 10 min. :)

Comment: Thanks, I am connected to internet and I did check the box to do updates.

Comment: What type of internet connection are you using? What is your regular internet speed?

Comment: It would help us if you tell us exactly what messages are on screen. Also if these messages change over time.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your computer's specifications and the maximum download speed from your ISP a full installation of Ubuntu from start to finish with the options of *Download updates while installing Ubuntu* and *Install third-party software* selected could take anywhere from 10 minutes to an hour. Normally it takes about a half hour to install Ubuntu. Some stages of the Ubuntu installation process go faster than others. The longest two stages are downloading updates and unpacking and installing packages.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you checked at the beginning of the installation (download updates or not), the installation time may vary from 30 minutes to two hours approx, unless your internet connection is somewhat slow.