# Does creating ext4 file system takes a really long time or is it my drive that is broken right now?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, external-hdd, ext4

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my external drive which has 1TB of storage. I parititioned it to be 104GB so that it wouldn't take that long to process. When I tried installling it, it takes probably more than 5 hours and it still installing. I clicked on the drop down next to the text and it says "Windows manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12)". Idk what that means because I'm new to linux and my internal drive couldn't be detected so that's why I'm installing it in my external drive.

Comment: You haven't provided any OS/release details which often provide clues; but if it's a new/clean drive; creating partitions is usually very fast as nothing outside of partition table entries is done.  If however you are shrinking a large data drive to create the space - that's a very different thing (a long/slow resize being required to create space before the new partition can be made in a 'jiffy').   If you're only creating partition entries & not resizing; check drive health - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long should installing Ubuntu take?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230134/how-long-should-installing-ubuntu-take)